# second Operating system on ssd doesnt seem on grub menu

Tags: grub2, ssd, fedora

I have ssd and a hdd
I installed ubuntu on hdd , after this fedora on ssd however on grub menu only ubuntu appears. I am uploading the text file of boot info script please help .

```
Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]
```

============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

=> Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 94 for .
 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 99 for .

sda1: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       ext2
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  Ubuntu 13.04
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                   /boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf
```

sda2: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       Extended Partition
Boot sector type:  Unknown
Boot sector info:
```

sda5: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       swap
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

sdb1: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /grub2/grub.cfg
```

sdb2: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       LVM2_member
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048   476,096,511   476,094,464  83 Linux
/dev/sda2         476,098,558   488,396,799    12,298,242   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         476,098,560   488,396,799    12,298,240  82 Linux swap / Solaris

Drive: sdb ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

Disk /dev/sdb: 60.0 GB, 60022480896 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7297 cylinders, total 117231408 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *          2,048     1,026,047     1,024,000  83 Linux
/dev/sdb2           1,026,048   117,229,567   116,203,520  8e Linux LVM

"blkid" output: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        5894b892-2ac5-4f5d-a65d-1adc979c7b4a   ext2
/dev/sda5        2afdc36a-55b4-4ae2-8933-90bad39cc23f   swap
/dev/sdb1        e24bbc02-6195-4cc3-8760-6e96458ace18   ext4
/dev/sdb2        CU6hgj-6osE-y4Pv-sefJ-uDrj-8lf3-DWgOm4 LVM2_member

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda1        /                        ext2       (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdb1        /media/ty-1/e24bbc02-6195-4cc3-8760-6e96458ace18 ext4       (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have 2 HDDs, each with a GRUB installed to their MBRs, but you can only boot one GRUB (at a time), namely the one on the first hard drive with the Ubuntu installed on it (sda). The solution is to update Ubuntu's `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` so it will detect and include Fedora as well:

`sudo update-grub`